# Problem accessing file from remote server shared directory on same network in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, webclient

Asp.net web application is hosted in IIS on a server and it access the file in a Shared Directory on other server sharing the same network and getting error

[Access to file path "\ServerName\some\folder\on\disk\file.txt" is denied"].
i've given rights to IISUser, MachineUser until Everyone but got no luck.

But when i access the path from same server IIS from a Utility(POC).It accesses the path and download the string but from web application it is returning the error.

```
string filepath = @"\\ServerName\some\folder\on\disk\file.txt"
using(Webclient client = new Webclient())
{
  filetext = client.DownloadString(filepath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for "Access to file path "\ServerName\some\folder\on\disk\file.txt" is denied"" is your application pool identity don't have permission to access the share folder.
Please replace the application pool identity with your domain account and ensure the domain account have permission to acess the share folder.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]